# Transforming a transfer function into a differential equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, s-function

I have the following code in matlab:

```
syms s
num = [2.4e8];
den = [1 72 90^2];
hs = poly2sym(num, s)/poly2sym(den, s);
hs
```

[image]

```
f = ilaplace(hs)
```

[image]

The inverse Laplace transform converts the transfer function in the "s" domain to the time domain.I want to know if there is a way to transform the s-domain equation to a differential equation with derivatives. The following figure is an example:

[image: This is just an example]

I'm trying to implement a dynamic system in an s-function and I need to put it in this format to be able to access the system states.
I tried to work with the state space of this system but it's giving an error that I couldn't solve, I even have an unanswered question here, about this: "[S-Function error message: Output returned by S-function 'Hi_plant_sfcn' in 'untitled/S-Function' during flag=3 call must be a real vector of length 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68269884/s-function-error-message-output-returned-by-s-function-hi-plant-sfcn-in-unti)".
If anyone knows how to do this, I appreciate it.

Comment: "but it's giving an error that I couldn't solve" Which error did it give?

Comment: this is the question that is unanswered. It's the same equation but in state space and inside an s-function.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68269884/s-function-error-message-output-returned-by-s-function-hi-plant-sfcn-in-unti